# British idioms in America

Tags: idioms, american-english, british-english

There is a question I asked a lot of people about that and everyone answered differently.

---

Can I use British idioms in America or in front of an American citizen? Because some beautiful idioms are British and we do not have American version of them like:

Do not beat around the bush

> [image: screenshot of Cambridge Dictionary entry for "Beat around the bush"]

Some of them said:

1. They will laugh to you
2. They hate and cannot stand each other
3. It is ok to use

And guess what? All of them were true and I saw all those answers in movies. But  **finally**  is it ok to use or not? If yes or no, Why? Or where I can and where I can not?

> Thanks for helping me❤

Comment: *Some* Americans might not recognize certain BrE usages, but most *will* be recognized (either because the American has heard them before, or because *in context* the meaning is obvious anyway). For the reverse situation, Brits will almost always recognize AmE usages, even if we don't normally *generate* them ourselves. That "imbalance" is partly because American culture dominates the world, and partly because there are far *more* Americans than Brits, so we encounter their ways more than they encounter ours.

Comment: As a typical example, Americans often snigger at the BrE usage *I'm just popping out for a quick fag* because they "pretend" they understand ***fag*** as meaning ***male homosexual***. But they only do that for the sake of humour. Almost all Americans know perfectly well that ***fag*** is used in BrE to mean ***cigarette***.

Comment: That dictionary entry says that 'beat around the bush' is mainly a US idiom, and 'beat about the bush' is a mainly UK idiom. They are so similar that Americans will understand the British version and vice versa. In many expressions, 'around' may be replaced by 'about' without destroying meaning (in US and British English).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - do they still do that? I thought it had gone the way of Mrs Slocombe's pussy.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Who? What? Do Brits still pop out for a fag, or do Americans still snigger?

Comment: @FumbleFingers - do Americans still snigger? I'd have thought that even cowpunchers in the remotest parts of Wyoming have heard that Brits call cigarettes 'fags', and have got (gotten?) over it. I understand that the word 'shag' is wildly funny in the US now, thanks to  the execrable Austin Powers films, and also everybody there now knows that  'wank' is not just a typical New York dentist surname.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I expect the Internet, globalization in general, and the rise of planet-spanning Anglophone entertainment giants (Netflix, Amazon, Apple TV,...) means we all tend to *know* previously "regionally distinct" usages. And if they meet a need, we'll eventually start to actually *use* the most useful terms from abroad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a humourous saying that British and American people are "divided by a common language". It's true that there are some words and idioms that are unique to each dialect, but we understood each other perfectly well. Most of the English-speaking world is familiar with American idioms through US movies and TV shows being widely syndicated. As for the other way around - my experience in the USA as a British person has mainly been that certain things I've said have been *noticed* as being "typically British", but rarely have I not been understood. When confusion has arisen it is usually over terms for things, not idioms or sayings.

Your example of 'beat around the bush' is possibly a misunderstanding on your part - that note in your dictionary is pointing out an alternate UK variation, not saying that the idiom itself is uniquely UK English. [This ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=beat%20around%20the%20bush&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3) shows its use in US English publications only.

As for whether you will be "laughed at" for using idioms from other dialects - I presume you are not a native English speaker anyway. There are probably lots of analogies, metaphors and idioms you might use from your own native language while speaking English anyway, so using a British one is hardly going to stand out.

Comment: Thank you so much ❤